# Need to animate an image like a knight rider bulbs

Tags: css, html, animation

[image]

I do have above "png" image.Can you tell me how to animate it like a knight rider bulbs way ? I don't have that much of experience about the animation.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple and quick sample would be like:

```css
i {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: kn 1.6s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: kn 1.6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

i:nth-child(9){
    -webkit-animation-delay:0;
    animation-delay:0;
}
i:nth-child(8){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-0.2s;
    animation-delay:-0.2s;
}
i:nth-child(7){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-0.4s;
    animation-delay:-0.4s;
}
i:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-0.6s;
    animation-delay:-0.6s;
}
i:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-0.8s;
    animation-delay:-0.8s;
}
i:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-1s;
    animation-delay:-1s;
}
i:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-1.2s;
    animation-delay:-1.2s;
}
i:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-1.4s;
    animation-delay:-1.4s;
}
i:nth-child(1){
    -webkit-animation-delay:-1.6s;
    animation-delay:-1.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes kn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.1;
    }
}

@keyframes kn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div> 
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
</div>
```

Play with it to make the timing what you want.

Comment: Wow,really awesome.Can you do one thing though.Can you change it to blue colour which is on the above image ? Thanks.

Comment: Just change the background from red to your color - i dont have a colorpicker available. Also knight rider has red lights :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking still, there is this one.
https://codepen.io/Trent-Williams/pen/jOQEVVW

```css
html, body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
  height: auto;
  background: black;
}

#kitt {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:50px;
  width: 196px;
  height: 18px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px grey;
}
.one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven, .eight {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f4dbde;
  opacity: .9;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 11px red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
}

.one {
   -webkit-animation-name: first ;
}
.two {
  -webkit-animation-name: second ;
}
.three {
  -webkit-animation-name: third ;
}
.four {
  -webkit-animation-name: fourth ;
}
.five {
  -webkit-animation-name: fifth ;
}
.six {
  -webkit-animation-name: sixth ;
}
.seven {
  -webkit-animation-name: seventh ;
}
.eight {
  -webkit-animation-name: eighth ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first {
  0%   {opacity:1;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0.55;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0.35;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0.25;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0.15;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0.07;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0;}
  100%   {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes second {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:1;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0.55;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0.35;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0.25;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0.15;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0.07;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0;}
  92.8%   {opacity:1;}
  100%   {opacity:0.75;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes third {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:1;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0.55;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0.35;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0.25;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0.15;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0.07;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0;}
  85.68%   {opacity:1;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0.55;}
  100%   {opacity:0.35;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fourth {

  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0;}
  21.42%   {opacity:1;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0.55;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0.35;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0.25;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0.15;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0.07;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0;}
  78.54%   {opacity:1;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0.55;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0.35;}
  100%   {opacity:0.25;}


}

@-webkit-keyframes fifth {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0;}
  28.56%   {opacity:1;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0.55;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0.35;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0.25;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0.15;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0.07;}
  71.4%   {opacity:1;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0.55;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0.35;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0.25;}
  100%   {opacity:0.15;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sixth {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0;}
  35.7%   {opacity:1;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0.55;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0.35;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0.25;}
  64.26%   {opacity:1;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0.55;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0.35;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0.25;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0.15;}
  100%   {opacity:0.07;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes seventh {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0;}
  42.84%   {opacity:1;}
  49.98%   {opacity:0.35;}
  57.12%   {opacity:1;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0.55;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0.35;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0.25;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0.15;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0.07;}
  100%   {opacity:0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes eighth {
  0%   {opacity:0;}
  7.14%   {opacity:0;}
  14.28%   {opacity:0;}
  21.42%   {opacity:0;}
  28.56%   {opacity:0;}
  35.7%   {opacity:0;}
  42.84%   {opacity:0;}
  49.98%   {opacity:1;}
  57.12%   {opacity:0.55;}
  64.26%   {opacity:0.35;}
  71.4%   {opacity:0.25;}
  78.54%   {opacity:0.15;}
  85.68%   {opacity:0.07;}
  92.8%   {opacity:0;}
  100%   {opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<div id='kitt'>
    <div class='one'></div>
    <div class='two'></div>
    <div class='three'></div>
    <div class='four'></div>
    <div class='five'></div>
    <div class='six'></div>
    <div class='seven'></div>
    <div class='eight'></div>
    <div class='nine'></div>
 </div>
```